# MDX: using distinct count in YTD for calculated member

Tags: sum, distinct, mdx

I have created new measure that counts distinct policies (this measure is called `FK Policy Distinct Count`).

Then I created new **calculated member** called `CountPolicyEndorsesNull` which counts all policies from `FK Policy Distinct Count` using a filter:

`(([Policy].[Endorses].&[0],[FK Policy Distinct Count])`.

Than I did new **calculated member** called `CountPolicy`:

`SUM(EXCEPT([Policy].[Policy Status].[Policy Status],[Policy].[Policy Status].&[Void]), [Measures].[CountPolicyEndorsesNull])`

Next, I created a new member `CountNewBound`

```
SUM(
    {
        [Submission].[Tran Type].&[New], [Submission].[Tran Type].&[Developed]
    }, 
    [Measures].[CountPolicy]
)
```

And finally, `YTDCountNewBound`

```
SUM(YTD([Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember), [Measures].[CountNewBound])
```

Obviously, SUM function doesn't work in this case. Any idea how to make proper YTD count for calculated member?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it shows right values. Screenshot is because of comparison: 1+3+1=5 and it matches YTDCountNewBound for 2011-01-06, but Grand Total is 4

Comment: Well, my question is how to get YTD count in calculated member? Is it possible at all? Obviously it's not possible using SUM.

Comment: I don't understand second part of your comment...

Comment: Is not enough with: YTD([Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember) for you?

Comment: Where should I put this code?

Comment: I don't understand how do I relate this with CountNewBound

Comment: I have tried this but no success: (YTD([Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember), [Measures].[CountNewBound])

Comment: If you mean this: `YTD([Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember), [Measures].[CountNewBound]` than I have to say that this syntax doesn't work. If I put it inside brackets (`(...)` or `{...}`) it also doesn't work (but syntax is good)

Comment: No luck - error: Aggregate functions cannot be used on calculated members in the Measure dimension

Answer (score 0):

Distinct count is a special measure which should be managed with a little more care. The rational behind this is that the when evaluating the measure a set of previous values is kept in memory. In order to improve performance, this structure is not passed and it's quickly converted to a scalar value.

Going back to your problem :

Distinct count can be evaluated over a tuple without problem, but you'll get in problems once you try to evaluate over a set of tuples. A possible, but costly and not always possible, is to create a hierarchy of values so you can convert your set in a member of a dimension.

In your case instead of using YTD([Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember) function using another hierarchy -> [Invoice Date].[YTD Date Hierarchy].

All this depends on the specific OLAP implementation you're using, but I guess holds true for mainly all OLAP vendors.